# How to sum matrix elements based on finding the first (and second) non-zero elements of each row?

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix:

[image]

I would like to sum all the first non-zero elements of each row so that I get a value of

$$25.5317 + 8.85471 + 6.90018 + 32.9436 + ... $$

and so on and simply ignore zero rows.

Similarly  I would like to do the same again for the second non-zero elements from each row so that I get:

$$29.1235 + 11.0472 + 41.2639$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 tbl = RandomChoice[{.5, .1, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05} ->
     Range[0, 9], {10, 10}];
 tbl//TableForm
```

[image]

Remove all zeros from  `tbl` and add zeros to the right to make a full array:

```
PadRight[tbl /. (0) -> Sequence[], Automatic] // TableForm
```

[image]

Then sum each column:

```
 Tr /@ (Transpose@PadRight[tbl /. (0) -> Sequence[], Automatic])
 (* {55, 59, 36, 28, 38, 14, 9} *)
```

**Update:** To get a matrix with dimensions `{nrows, ncolumns}` from `PadRight` change `Automatic` to `{nrows, ncolumns}`. So,

```
 Tr /@ (Transpose@PadRight[tbl /. (0) -> Sequence[], {10,10}])
 (* {55, 59, 36, 28, 38, 14, 9, 0 ,0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Hi @kguler, seems to work but I originally had 5 columns, now after sorting, it is 4 columns? Why is that? I need to maintain the column to be constant.

Comment: @sebastian, to get a matrix with dimensions `{nrows, ncolumns}` from `PadRight` change `Automatic` to `{nrows, ncolumns}`. (The setting `Automatic` adds as many columns as needed to remove raggedness.)

Answer (score 6):

Not as nice as the [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14669/106) given by [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler).  Nevertheless, as an alternative:

```
myarray = {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0},
  {0., 0., 0., 25.5317, 29.1235}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 8.85471}, {0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 6.90018}, {0., 
   0., 0., 0., 32.9436}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 29.1235}, {0., 0., 0., 
   2.47854, 11.0472}, {0., 0., 16.1408, 41.2639, 45.7614}, {0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0}}
```

(Using Flatten to transpose a ragged array):

```
Flatten[Select[#, FreeQ[#, 0. | 0] &] & /@ myarray, {2}]
```

=>

> {{25.5317, 8.85471, 6.90018, 32.9436, 29.1235, 2.47854, 
>     16.1408}, {29.1235, 11.0472, 41.2639}, {45.7614}}

Therefore,

```
Total /@ Flatten[Select[#, FreeQ[#, 0. | 0] &] & /@ myarray, {2}]
```

=>

> {121.973, 81.4346, 45.7614}

Comparing with [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler)'s method

```
tbl = RandomChoice[{.5, .1, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05, .05} ->
     Range[0, 9], {10, 10}];
Tr /@ (Transpose@PadRight[tbl /. (0) -> Sequence[], Automatic]) == 
 Total /@ Flatten[Select[#, FreeQ[#, 0. | 0] &] & /@ tbl, {2}]
```

=>

> True

**Edit**

Better, perhaps, is

```
Total /@ Flatten[DeleteCases[myarray, 0 | 0., 2], {2}]
```

However, the best variation on the Flatten approach, I recon, is given below (as a comment) by [rm -rf](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5/rm-rf):

```
Total[Flatten[# /. 0 | 0. -> Sequence[], {2}], {2}] &@myarray
```

=>

> {121.973, 81.4346, 45.7614}

Comment: I was about to write an answer with this same approach. It can also be written as: `Total[Flatten[# /. 0|0. -> Sequence[], {2}], {2}]&`

Comment: @rm -rf. That is a nice one! Thanks.

Comment: Tom and @rm-rf, actually I like your method better:).

Answer (score 3):

One can search for the first nonzero element in each row using `Cases`. Generate a random table:

```
m = Normal@SparseArray[
      Thread@{RandomInteger[{1, 12}, 14], RandomInteger[{1, 6}, 14]} :> RandomReal[], {12, 6}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and pick the first match in each row:

```
Flatten[Cases[#, _?(! PossibleZeroQ@# &), 1, 1] & /@ m]
```

Or extending the `Sequence` replacement method in kguler's answer:

```
m /. {0 | 0. -> Sequence[]} /. {} -> Sequence[] /. {x_?NumberQ, ___} :> x
```

> ```
> {0.252222, 0.998427, 0.0562231, 0.849365, 0.582891, 0.0896831, 0.31189, 0.524075}
> ```

To get the second nonzero element from each row:

```
m /. {0 | 0. -> Sequence[]} /. {} | {_} -> Sequence[] /. {_?NumberQ, x_, ___} :> x
```

> ```
> {0.949761, 0.841579, 0.0275406, 0.500705}
> ```

`Total` then does the summing.

Answer (score 3):

Using 1066's data

```
mat = {{0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0},
  {0., 0., 0., 25.5317, 29.1235}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 8.85471}, {0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 6.90018}, {0., 
   0., 0., 0., 32.9436}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 29.1235}, {0., 0., 0., 
   2.47854, 11.0472}, {0., 0., 16.1408, 41.2639, 45.7614}, {0., 0., 
   0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0}};
```

With `Slot` and `MapApply`

```
sum[m_, n_] := 
 Slot[n] & @@@ PadRight[mat //. 0 | 0. | {} :> Nothing] // Total

sum[mat, #] & /@ Range[3]
```

{121.973, 81.4346, 45.7614}