# Operations on elements of ragged lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of lists with different lengths, sorted from longest to shortest

```
 myLists = Sort[Table[RandomReal[1, RandomInteger[50]], {25}], Length@#1 > Length@#2 &];
```

I would like to add up all the first elements, then all the second, and so on elements for each list that has the required number of elements.

For example if my lists are

```
{
 {1,2,3},
 {4,5},
 {6}
}
```

Then I want to return

```
{11,7,3}
```

The following code performs this using For loops, but I am trying to figure out a better way of doing this.

```
sums = Table[0, {Max[Length /@ a]}];
(* For each row element up to the length of the longest list *)
For[j = 1, j <= Max[ Length /@ a], j++,
(* For each list *)
     For[k = 1, k <= Length[a], k++,
(* Add the element to the correct sum if it exists *)
            If[Length[a[[k]]] >= j,
                 sums[[j]] = sums[[j]] + a[[k, j]],
                 Break[]
              ]
        ]
   ]
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to simply pad every thing to the right length with `0` and then add? Or are zeros appropriate values that can exist in your ragged length list?

Comment: We have [just had a question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14663/106) that requires a similar solution.  One way is to use `Flatten` to transpose a 'ragged' array.  For example `Total /@ Flatten[list, {2}]` =>  {11, 7, 3}

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like Total /@ Flatten[list,{2}] will do the trick.  So much simplier!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second argument of `Flatten` can be used to [transpose ragged lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3644/5) (also see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126/5) by Leonid). With this, you can use the second argument of `Total` to sum each sublist. The following is similar to my comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/how-to-sum-matrix-elements-based-on-finding-the-first-and-second-non-zero-elem#comment43544_14677):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}} 
list ~Flatten~ {2} ~Total~ {2}
(* {11, 7, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `PadRight[]` to make a square array (with for example `Empty` to fill in the blank spots), then `Transpose[]` it and delete all the `Empty`'s. Finally, you can `Total[]` all the rows.

Random data:

```
a = RandomInteger[{0, 20}, #] & /@ Reverse[Range[10]];
```

Then:

```
Map[Total, 
 DeleteCases[#, x_ /; x === Empty] & /@ 
  Transpose[PadRight[a, {10, 10}, Empty]]]
```

It's a bit of a workaround, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

As A. Goossens mentions, one can use `PadRight[]` as an alternative, though in fact one can leverage the fact that

> `PadRight[list]` pads a ragged array list with zeros to make it full.

so:

```
Total[PadRight[{{a, b}, {c, d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}]]
   {a + c + g, b + d + h, e + i, f}
```

Comment: I explicity used `Empty` so the data stays the same even if there are already zeros in it. For the solution it doesn't make any difference, that's true.