# Part of the nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a nested list where sublists have unequal length. How can I extract all values of the list at specific level ignoring errors if the value at that level doesn't exist. For example:

```
lst={{1,2},{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, g, k}, {l}}
```

How can I extract the values at position 4 of each sublist and get `{d,h}`.
No surprise that `lst[[All,4]]` returns an error, but I don't even know where to start. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: you could *first* pad all your lists to the appropriate length (eg 4) with something like `lst=PadRight[#,4,Null]&/@lst` and *then* do `lst=Part[lst,All,4]`. Then, you could get `{d,h}` by executing something like`Cases[lst, Except[Null],1]`.

Comment: @user42582. I think you can just do `PadRight[lst]`, (as long as none of the values you extract from the list are zero).

Comment: @march sure you can... there's a million different ways you can go about doing it

Comment: Somewhat related: [(14688)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14688/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Cases[lst, {_, _, _, x_, ___} :> x]
```

> {d, h}

Comment: `Cases[lst, {x__, y_, z___} :> y /; Length[{x}] == 3]`

Comment: For generality consider `Repeated`: `Cases[lst, {Repeated[_, {3}], x_, ___} :> x]`

Answer (score 8):

You could "transpose" your `lst` using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) (1), and then take the 4 element:

```
Flatten[lst, {{2}, {1}}][[4]]
```

> {d, h}

1. [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/5478)

Comment: Shoot. Eight seconds late. Why do `Flatten[lst, {{2}, {1}}]` instead of just `Flatten[lst, {2}]`?

Comment: @march I think using {2} is simpler, but the {{2}, {1}} (or {{2}}) form is better documented.

Comment: @march, that certainly works; in my case, I prefer Carl's version since there is an explicit reminder of which levels are being flattened.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another approach using [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) that's perhaps a bit more explicit about what's happening:

```
Query[DeleteMissing@#&, 4]@lst
```

The slightly strange `@#&` part is there to "hide" `DeleteMissing` from query to make sure it's applied after the selector `4`. (In "`Query` language": we make the typically descending operator `DeleteMissing` ascending)

Comment: my experience with `Query`, albeit a short one I have to admit, was not a happy one-had trouble wrapping my head around ascending vs descending operators etc-imo it's too much hassle with few rewards

Comment: `Query[4] /@ lst // DeleteMissing` strikes me as a touch simpler.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard True - the other one is contained in an operator though, which might be valuable in some cases...

Comment: Indeed it might :-)

Answer (score 5):

Arguably the most pedestrian approach has not yet been posted: pre-filter the list.

```
Select[lst, Length@# > 3 &][[All, 4]]
```

> ```
> {d, h}
> ```

A slightly more convenient formulation of the same idea might be:

```
get[n_][x_] := If[Length@x < n, ## &[], x[[n]]]

get[4] /@ lst
```

> ```
> {d, h}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Just for something different:

```
ReleaseHold@PadRight[lst, Automatic, Hold[Sequence[]]][[All, 4]]
```