# Sorting Matrix Elements

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sorting

I have matrix `in` as shown, consisting of real numbers and 0. How can I sort it to become `out` as shown?

```
in ={
   {0, 0, 3.411, 0, 1.343},
   {0, 0, 4.655, 2.555, 3.676},
   {0, 3.888, 0, 3.867, 1.666}
   };
out ={
   {1.343, 3.411, 0, 0, 0},
   {2.555, 3.676, 4.655, 0, 0},
   {1.666, 3.867, 3.888, 0, 0}
   };
```

This is related to a [question I asked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/). It is much easier to add the columns by sorting it this way than in previous question, and easier to visualize than trying to take the first non-zero value in a row.

Comment: Re: "consisting of real numbers and 0" -> "Consisting of the humanity and me"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would be to replace zeros with `Null`, map `Sort` onto it and then replace `Null` with zeros. This works because the default sorting function `OrderedQ` will place `Null` at the end, as per your needs.

```
mat =  {{0, 0, 3.411, 0, 1.343}, {0, 0, 4.655, 2.555, 3.676}, {0, 3.888, 0, 3.867, 1.666}};
Map[Sort, mat /. (0 | 0.) -> Null] /. Null -> 0
(*  1.343   3.411   0       0   0
    2.555   3.676   4.655   0   0
    1.666   3.867   3.888   0   0 *)
```

Comment: This is much faster and cleaner than my solution.

Comment: @AndyRoss Yours can be made faster simply by making it `f[0|0.] = Infinity`, since the OP said that it only contains zeros. Right now, it's unnecessarily testing every element (twice) with `PossibleZeroQ`

Comment: `(0 | 0.)` computers...

Comment: Right. But the custom sorting function is going to be much slower regardless.

Comment: Hi @rm -rf like your solution

Comment: I would change "will place Null at the end" by "will place any symbol after any number"

Answer (score 6):

You can map `Sort` over the rows using a custom ordering function which treats 0 as infinity.

```
data = RandomChoice[{0, 1}, {5, 5}]*RandomReal[{1, 10}, {5, 5}];

f[0|0.]= \[Infinity];
f[x_] := x
Sort[#, f[#1] <= f[#2] &] & /@ data

(*{{6.07883, 7.33113, 0., 0., 0.}, {2.74761, 0., 0., 0., 0.},
   {6.09223, 8.11442, 0., 0., 0.}, {3.16126, 4.72089, 7.72369, 0.,0.}, 
   {9.25964, 0., 0., 0., 0.}}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since what you are doing is basically sorting each row, but 0 is treated as highest value. One way is to replace all zeros with `Infinity` before sorting and changing back after

```
r = RandomChoice[{0, Random[]}, {3, 5}];
r // MatrixForm

(Sort[#] & /@ (r /. {(0 | 0.) -> Infinity})) /. {Infinity -> 0} // MatrixForm
```

[image: Output]

**Edit** I like Andy Ross's solution better

Comment: Btw, you could also do something like `RandomChoice[{0, Random[]}, {3, 5}]`

Comment: Or if your list is big, a faster solution may be `Times@@Through@{RandomReal, RandomChoice}[{0, 1}, {3, 5}]`, adding `//Chop` if you care about having integer `0`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
MapApply[in[[##]]&]@MapIndexed[{First@#2,#1}&,(Ordering/@Replace[in, 
    0->\[Infinity],2])]

(* {
    {1.343,3.411,0,0,0},
    {2.555,3.676,4.655,0,0},
    {1.666,3.867,3.888,0,0}
   } *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
PadRight[#, Length@in[[1]], 0] & /@ Sort /@ DeleteCases[in, 0 | 0., 2]

(* {
    {1.343, 3.411, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {2.555, 3.676, 4.655, 0, 0}, 
    {1.666, 3.867,  3.888, 0, 0}
   } *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
in = {{0, 0, 3.411, 0, 1.343}, {0, 0, 4.655, 2.555, 3.676}, {0, 3.888,
     0, 3.867, 1.666}};
```

A possible solution

```
Sort /@ (in I - Unitize[in]) // Im
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
SortBy[#, # /. 0 -> {} &] & /@ in
```

This works because `{}` will be placed after atomic elements such as real numbers.  If your zeros may not always be precise (head Integer) you may use:

```
SortBy[#, # /. x_ /; x == 0 -> {} &] & /@ in
```

Comment: That is a nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Define your own ordering function:

```
f[_, 0] := 1
f[0, _] := -1
f[x_, y_] := x <= y

Sort[#, f] & /@ in // MatrixForm
```

[image]